# How to authenticate email and password with laravel 5.3 manually?

Tags: php, mysqli, laravel-5.3, bcrypt

**Hello Everyone**
My question is how can we authenticate our email and password in laravel 5.3 ?
I am not using Auth here , I am trying to create login system manually
**This is user register method**
`public function post_register(Request $request){
            $this->validate($request , [
                'username' => 'required|' , 
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:registers' ,
                'password' => 'required|min:6', 
                'cp' => 'required|same:password']);
            $data = new Register;
            $data->username = $request->username;
            $data->email = $request->email;
            $data->password = bcrypt($request->password);
            $data->save();
            return Redirect::back()->with('success' , 'user registred');
    }`


**This is login method**

```
public function post_login(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request , [
        'email' => 'required|email' ,
        'password' => 'required']);

 $data = Register::where('email' , $request->email)->exists();
 if($data){
     Session::put('email' , $request->email);
     return Redirect::to('profile');

 }
 else{
    return Redirect::to('login');

 }
```

this code is working , but problem is that if i enter registered email and unregistered  password then it redirect to profile page.
i am not able to authenticate user with email and password because i am using bcrypt() hash function in password and when i try to match  http request with stored password , it show error 
Please help me ,Thanks

Comment: You can bcrypt the password at login and then check it right? If I understand you correctly, the only thing that's going wrong is the password check.

Comment: so what should i do now? how can i check both email and password ?

Comment: You can either rewrite your query to check for both the email and password or get the user and manual check it the password in database and request match. `if (data) --> if (bcrypt(request->password) === $data->password` in pseudocode

Comment: I tried sir but bcrypt() changed its value when i used it on  request->password and  i was entering correct password

Comment: That's pretty much the point right? See @pari's answer for a working solution

Comment: No sir its not working

Comment: @DeepGaganGuru Have a look at my new answer, and try implementing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wont work because you are comparing the string results of the hash which isnt correct.

**Changes you Register Function**

```
$data->password = Hash::make($request->password);
```

**Change Your Login function**

```
public function post_login(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request , [
        'email' => 'required|email' ,
        'password' => 'required']);

    $data = Register::where('email' , $request->email)->first();
    if($data){ 
        if(Hash::check($request->password, $data->password)){
            Session::put('email' , $request->email);
            return Redirect::to('profile');
        }
    }
    return Redirect::to('login');
}
```

**Explanation**

These changes allow you to use Laravel's built in Hashing functionality for Generating Hashes At Registration & Calculating if a hash is valid during login.

Comment: ErrorException in userController.php line 55:
Trying to get property of non-object              ..This error show on page

Comment: I just realised the issue. Try changing the `exists()` to `first()`

Comment: I tried sir , this time it does not show any error and redirect back to login

Comment: Done sir , its working now  , you just did little mistake in code .if(Hash::check($request->email, $data->password)){     ..it should be if(Hash::check($request->password, $data->password)){        ..Thanks so much sir

Comment: Glad to have helped :). Please accept my answer if it has worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this.

```
$data = Register::where('email' , $request->email)
                ->where('password' ,bcrypt($request->password))
                ->exists();
```

Comment: You can't check a `bcrypt()` result against strings due to the hard salt that is used each time `bcrypt()` is ran. Resulting in difference string each time. They need to be calculated